# Storing object properties inside state

Tags: reactjs

I have a state in React.

```
this.state = {
  loggedUser: '',
  playersList: []
};
```

And then I make a request to the server API and get an object back. Then I try to save it to state with:

```
  this.setState({ response })
```

But now in state there is the object and it's properties nested under it.

```
this.state = {
  loggedUser: '',
  playersList: [],
  response: {
    ...
  }
};
```

Is there a way to save all the properties directly into the state?
I want it to look like that:

```
this.state = {
  loggedUser: '',
  playersList: [],
  response_attr1: ,
  response_attr2: ,
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the spread operator:

`this.setState({ ...response })`

For example:

```
const thing = {a: 0, b: 1}
console.log({c: 2, ...thing})
```

gives you:

```
{ c: 2, a: 0, b: 1 }
```

You can read more about it [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-the-spread-syntax-f5c35525f754).